# How can I prevent Vim duplicating my text when I exit insert mode?

Tags: vim

I'm using Vim in the zsh shell on OSX.

[image: my-image-of-my-terminal]

In the image you can see that I have created a test text on the left side. When I exit insert mode (using <kbd>Esc</kbd>), Vim duplicates my text a few times.

You can see my Vim editor when I exited the insert mode on the right side of the image.

Why does Vim do that and how can I prevent it?

Comment: I have a typo in the Title:  * vim editor

Comment: Did you accidentally type a number before entering insert mode?

Comment: I dont think so,  but could be.

Comment: Can you please check? Because, for example, typing `<Esc>3ihello<Esc>` would result in `hellohellohello`.

Comment: ok probably i did, because now it doesnt duplicate my text when i exit the insert mode

Comment: But what happens when i accedently enter a number, does it duplicate the text times the number that i typed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you don't accidentally type a number before entering insert mode.

Like any other action, entering text in insert mode can be repeated by prepending the command with typing a number.

For example, typing <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>`hello`<kbd>Esc</kbd> from normal mode results in the text `hellohellohello` entered.

If you're unsure whether you have already typed a number, you can cancel any repetition by typing <kbd>Esc</kbd> again before entering insert mode.